# Loop in Django tempates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have two variables, `name = ["Fedora", "Ubuntu"]` and `state = {"Fedora": "up", "Ubuntu": "down"}`.

How do I display this data in a loop?

```
{% for s in state %}
   {% for n in state %}
      {{ n }} {{ s }}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Variable "n" is displayed four times instead of two times.

Comment: did you mean the inner for loop to be "for n in name" instead of "for n in state"?

Comment: Sorry made ​​a mistake. I mean first variable on loop name not state

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
{% for n,s in state.items %}
{{ n }}: {{ s }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yeah, if you have a list of keys anyways, you might as well just use the dictionary named `state`.  Less code to update in the future!

Comment: It's better to use `iteritems` in 2.x.

Comment: Anytime, don't forget to "accept" the answer if it solves your problem.